# mouseenter and mouseleave issue with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a parent div 'A' and on hover that div another div 'B' will be displayed and this second div is not a child div.It is a separate div.Both divs are positioned absolutely.

On mouse leave the second div which is 'B', it should disappear.But it is not disappearing.Actually I am not sure if it possible because when you leave the second div you are still over the first div and that's why the mousenter function is still triggered.

html code

```
<div class="portitem">Some content</div>
<div class="overlaygallery"></div>
```

CSS

```
.portitem {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#000;
}
.overlaygallery {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 204, 0.9);
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 999;
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.portitem').mouseover(function () {
    $('.overlaygallery').css("display", "block");

});

$(".overlaygallery").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
});
```

I have created a fiddle. It's http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/Gyn8c/

Is there any other tricks.Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a really strange behavior you're looking for. It's possible with a little JS tricks, but are you sure you need this exact kind of behavior?

Comment: Other than using `visibility` for the second function I don't see any other possibilities without making changes to your code - http://jsfiddle.net/Gyn8c/3/

Comment: @Prithviraj Mitra: Why don't you make them parent and child? It'll be a lot easier

Comment: you can even go with opacity approach, if you just want to hide and show only on hover... http://jsfiddle.net/M7FPX/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/Gyn8c/11/

I had to make them parent and child. It looks the same, and does what you wanted.

```
$('.overlaygallery').mouseout(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.portitem').
    mouseenter(function () { $('.overlaygallery').show(); }).
    mouseleave(function () { $('.overlaygallery').hide(); });
```

Comment: If you leave overlaygallery and enter it again without leaving portitem it won't be shown with this code.

Comment: @italy.. don't you feel when i come back to inner div from outer div, it will not show innerdiv.

Comment: @Kasma, that's not what he asked for. And if he'll ask for it, it can be done easily

Comment: Excellent piece of coding.Thank you so much @Itay.Yes I have understood the trick now.**** stars. :)

Answer (score 2):

Reading all this discussion looks like, you need to show div B when mouse is on div B, then go with opacity approach if you are performing anything based on div visibility or display anywhere in code.

```
$('.overlaygallery').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
},

function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    });
});
```

.portitem {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#000;
}

```
.overlaygallery {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 204, 0.9);
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity :0;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M7FPX/2/)

Comment: Pretty but OP wants overlaygallery to appear once the mouse crosses portitem, not overlaygallery directly.

Comment: Thanks Kasma for your idea.If you please see ltay's solution that's what I am gonna use.

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues with your code:

1. Hidden elements don't fire `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` events. To work around this, one can use opacity instead, which has pretty good cross browser support.
2. portitem mouseover was running immediately after overlaygallery mouseleave, so when the latter tried to hide itself portitem would show it again. You can work around this using the eventData provided by jQuery, specifically the property `toElement`.

It's a bit verbose and not very elegant, but it does exactly what you were after, if I understood correctly:

```
var cancelMouseOver = false;

$('.portitem').mouseenter(function (e) {
    if(!cancelMouseOver) {
        $('.overlaygallery').css("opacity", 1);
    } else {
        cancelMouseOver = false;
    }
});

$('.portitem').mouseleave(function (e) {
    $('.overlaygallery').css("opacity", 0);
});

$(".overlaygallery").mouseenter(function (e) {
    $(this).css("opacity", 1);
});

$(".overlaygallery").mouseleave(function (e) {
    $(this).css("opacity", 0);

    if($(e.toElement).hasClass("portitem")) {
        cancelMouseOver = true;
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TxGhk/1/)**

You might want to reconsider whether you need explicitly this though, perhaps a simpler approach would do too for what you need.

Comment: Thanks Mahn for your idea.Actually it is now sorted out using @ltay's solution.If you please see his fiddle that's the one which I wanted.Thanks for your great effort though.Cheers.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra with his method, if you leave the yellow box and enter it again *without* leaving the black box, it won't appear again. Are you aware of that? My implementation considered that, that's why it's a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hover function of jQuery which takes 2 parameters, what to do on mouseenter and what to do on mouseleave. It looks something like this, 
Remaining logic can be put inside these functions.

$("#id").hover(function(){},function(){})

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.portitem').hover(function () {
    $('.overlaygallery').css("display", "block");
    },function () {
    $('.overlaygallery').css("display", "none");
});

$('.overlaygallery').mouseout(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```